# Check array value? - True or False (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have an array in which I push true or false values. And I only want to execute the next function if the array is completely true or completely. But because they are not strings, I can not check it with `in_array(...)`.

Does anybody know how I can check if an array is completely true or completely?

Greetings and Thank You! :D

Comment: `if (array_sum($myArray) == count($myArray)) { all true }`.... `if (array_sum($myArray) == 0) { all false }`

Comment: Just tested in PHP 7 and you can use booleans in the `in_array` function.

Comment: And how does it look with the in_array function?

Comment: if you are using PHP7 then what @Manulaiko is suggesting is correct.

Comment: @Jan `in_array($needle, $haystack)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = array_unique($array);
if(count($res) === 1 && $res[0]) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Why not `$res[0]===TRUE` ?  Please update or explain.

Comment: and for that matter, isn't `$res[0]` the same as `$res[0]===TRUE` ? shorter with same accuracy.

Comment: hmm, sorry I keep picking.... `count($res)==1` is also shorter with same accuracy.  Should I have written my own?  Please edit yours if you agree.

Comment: count($res)==1 is also fine but its good habit of using === in place of ==

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, but it's your answer so I'll bow out now.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if all the array have same value

Then check if it's TRUE or false.

```
if(count(array_count_values($array))===1){
  if($array[0]){
    // Completely TRUE; 
    }else{
    // Completely FALSE; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP >= 7.4

To check if all items are true:

```
... = array_reduce($array, fn ($carry, $item) => $carry && $carry === $item, true);
```

To check if all items are false:

```
... = array_reduce($array, fn ($carry, $item) => $carry && $carry !== $item, true);
```